# DotNet Naming rule for auto property fields

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

Is there a way to change the naming conventions for auto properties to camelCase.
E.g. with the .editorconfig file?

[image: screenshot vscode]

Thanks!

Comment: Even if this is not standard, I need this formatting for "one" of my projects. Found the solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the naming rules from this path: Visual Studio -> Tool -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Naming

[image]

Click the **Manage naming styles** button and add a naming style like this;
[image]

Then select the naming style that you created for Non-Field Members.
[image]

Comment: Many thanks @tolga-cakir, unfortunately I didn't write it earlier: use vscode. But that's how it worked.

Comment: Well that's not quite right. Of course, this applies to all non-field members. I specifically wanted to address only the auto property variables. But there won't be an option here because it's nonsensical.

Comment: you should check the snippets in vs code @Markus: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets

Answer (score 0):

For the *.editorconfig* file that would be:

```
dotnet_naming_rule.property_should_be_camelcase.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.property_should_be_camelcase.symbols = property
dotnet_naming_rule.property_should_be_camelcase.style = camelcase

dotnet_naming_symbols.property.applicable_kinds = property
dotnet_naming_symbols.property.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.property.required_modifiers =

dotnet_naming_style.camelcase.required_prefix =
dotnet_naming_style.camelcase.required_suffix =
dotnet_naming_style.camelcase.word_separator =
dotnet_naming_style.camelcase.capitalization = camel_case
```